# how to login in django from custom model

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

[This is my table of register user photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dOd5.png)

This is model.py

```
class SignupUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

this is my views.py for login my account page through this register user

```
def login_page(request):
    '''
    what code i write here ??
    '''

    context = {'form': SignupForm}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

please solve my views.py code on my login_page method .What i write here to login in this user profile ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that as you are using a seperate table to store user information. If you want them to login, then these user needs to be created in either [**`User`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) model or you can write a [**`custom user model`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model) on your own following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login as auth_login, authenticate
import logging as L

def login_page(request):
    post_data = request.POST
    user = authenticate(username=post_data['email'], password=post_data['password'])
    if user is None:
        L.warning('Authentication error wrong credentials')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        auth_login(request, user)
        L.INFO('Authentication ok')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

well there you can use the django build ins for the login and logoout, your code should look sth like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are doing this in the correct way. Django already provides some mechanics to create some custom user models.

You should create a model that extends django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser as described in [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

You can see that the [AbstractUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86a0231e0a087d4b909f76223cc55d5bbb673930/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L315) class already have all the field you need.

Once you have this model, you should register it as the User model in your settings files [as mentioned here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

You can then use the authentication system implemented by Django and you should be fine.

If the fields provided by AbstractUser are not the one you are looking for, you can take a step back. You will need to override from django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser, possibly also from django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin if you need the permissions system.
With a little bit of [tweaks and configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms), Django's built-in views and forms should work with your new model.

Managing initial user model is a lot of configuration and can be difficult to achieve in the first place. But by taking the time to understand how all of those classes and configuration keys work together, you should not have any problem with this. Don't forget to check the documentation for the auth system. It is quite heavy, but with a little bit of work you should find everything you need in it.

Comment: i can not want to use custom user model